# Writing Encrypted Data on DVD

Tags: dvd, burning, disk-encryption

I've tried Nero SecurDisc for writing Copy Protected, Password Protected files on DVD which requires Nero SecurDisc Viewer to decrypt them. But It doesn't seem to have an option to protect/encrypt filenames.

Is there any similar utility that has both options, for example like WinRAR has an option to encrypt names + data?

I was thinking about compress the files into .rar with encryption and then write them on DVD. Would it do the same that i'm trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean by copy protected?

Comment: Some kind of [Nero SecurDisc feature](http://www.securdisc.net/eng/faq.html#14) to protect PDFs. In my case, I'm only looking to write encrypted files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) container, put your data in there and then burn the container. That way, you only see one file on the DVD and can mount the container later.

Edit:

From the [FAQ](http://www.truecrypt.org/faq):

> **What will happen when a part of a TrueCrypt volume becomes corrupted?**
>
> In encrypted data, one corrupted bit usually corrupts the whole ciphertext block in which it occurred. The ciphertext block size used by TrueCrypt is 16 bytes (i.e., 128 bits). The mode of operation used by TrueCrypt ensures that if data corruption occurs within a block, the remaining blocks are not affected. See also the question 'What do I do when the encrypted filesystem on my TrueCrypt volume is corrupted?

Comment: Hm, so if container was corrupted, wouldn't i lose all the files inside that container?

Comment: If the header was corrupted, yes. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Recover_a_TrueCrypt_Volume But the same is true for a Rar-file.